# the exercises suggested/the suggested exercises

Tags: grammar

I´d like to know whether I could say these two sentences:

1) However, I have calculated that in order to complete **the exercises suggested**, it would take closer to....

2) However, I have calculated that in order to complete **the suggested exercises**, it would take closer to....

To my ears both sound pretty good.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please, could you tell me the difference between "the people concerned" and "the concerned people"? I´ve read the article linked (Hah, can I use it here?) but I still don´t get it - especially the difference between these two forms. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dominik, if you don't already know the difference, you really should be asking on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) Answers on ELU are not necessarily required to address the needs of non-native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok. I am sorry- didn´t know that. But the problem is that I can not reply to answers I am given there - I don´t have enough "points" to do so. From that standpoint would it be possible to give me a sort of last answer here?

Comment: Have a look at [What is the difference between an adjective before the noun and after the noun?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55643/). If you still don't fully understand the different usages, feel free to ask another question ***on ELL***.

Comment: I checked the ELL link that FumbleFingers cites immediately above, and I can't say the answers are terribly enlightening. It is certainly true that "concerned people" and "people concerned" have very different meanings, but I'm not at all persuaded that "navigable rivers" and "rivers navigable" do—and the same is true of "exercises suggested" and "suggested exercises" in the poster's question above. Anyone who can clearly and coherently explain the functional difference in meaning between the poster's two wordings should consider posting it as an answer here. It's not ELL simple, in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is the better sentence.

Option 1 sounds like a foreigner is speaking it.

Comment: That´s interesting. The option 1 is an original sentence which can be found in my textbook. However it didn´t sound quite good to me so I changed the order of these two words.

Answer (score 0):

If we shorten the clauses in question to a more manageable size, we get this pair of options:

> 1. Completing the exercises suggested would take X.
> 2. Completing the suggested exercises would take X.

To me, the meanings of these two statements seem functionally identical. There is a slightly stronger hint in the first sentence that the writer has omitted something relevant—namely, the identity of the suggester—since the first sentence isn't seamless in the way the second sentence is. In other words, a reader can more readily see the hole in the sentence structure

> Completing the exercises suggested [by some unnamed person] would take X.

than in the sentence structure

> Completing the suggested exercises[—suggested, that is, by some unnamed person—]would take X.

Of course, we're considering the sentence in a vacuum. The preceding sentence might have said something like this:

> Professor Barnstable suggested ten exercises designed to increase students' appreciation of the slide rule.

in which case the identity of the suggester is well established when the "exercises suggested"/ "suggested exercises" sentence rolls around, and that basis for distinguishing between wording 1 and wording 2 vanishes. As always, context is crucial to nuance.

The suggester's identity aside, the main distinction between wording 1 and wording 2 is the one that Tiffany gives in her answer: wording 1 sounds somewhat less colloquially conversational than wording 2 (though not terribly so, in my opinion) . But the actual meaning that the two wordings convey is the same, as nearly as I can tell.

---

In a comment beneath the poster's question, FumbleFingers points to a question on English Language Learners that asks [What is the difference between an adjective before the noun and after the noun?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55643/what-is-the-difference-between-an-adjective-before-the-noun-and-after-the-noun) In response to that question commenters and answerers address two sets of example wordings:

> 3. All rivers navigable are being patrolled.
> 4. All navigable rivers are being patrolled.

and

> 5. The people concerned are looking forward to seeing this event.
> 6. The concerned people are looking forward to seeing this event.

The difference between wording 5 and wording 6 is entirely attributable to the fact that *concerned* in the phrase "people concerned" means one thing ("affected") but *concerned* in the phrase "concerned people" means another ("worried"); consequently, it isn't a very helpful example to use as a basis for reaching conclusions about how "exercises suggested" and "suggested exercises" differ, since *suggested* has the same meaning in both positions.

The "rivers navigable"/"navigable rivers" pair is far more relevant to the OP's question here, which makes it not at all surprising to me that the accepted answer at ELL initially concludes that there didn't appear to be a difference in meaning between wording 3 and wording 4 above.

That's where I would have left matters; but the ELL answerer came back later and appended to the simple answer an argument asserting that the construction "navigable rivers" "may express either an ephemeral or a permanent characteristic, depending on the context," whereas the construction "rivers navigable" "connotes an ephemeral quality, one that is present at the moment, but doesn't always have to be." I'm not at all sure I buy that argument with respect to the word *navigable* in the "rivers navigable"/"navigable rivers" pair, and I don't buy it at all with respect to the word *suggested* in the "exercises suggested"/"suggested exercises" pair. As far as I can see, "exercises suggested" refers to exactly as ephemeral and/or permanent a thing as "suggested exercises."

My advice is to watch out for odd modifiers like *concerned* whose meaning may shift depending on whether they appear before or after the noun they modify. But otherwise (that is, if the modifier you're dealing with retains the same meaning regardless of whether it appears before or after the noun it modifies), though the "noun before modifier" form may sound less natural to some hearers than the "modifier before noun" form does, the two forms mean essentially the same thing.